# Sniffing https traffic of an android app

Tags: android, apk, sniffing, https-protocol

I want to do a challenge: automise some tasks that I do in a game so I can get the max of points.

To do that, I need to know the url called and the parameters that are used in the Game. After setting a genymotion station and made a proxy, I've discovered that the game won't start if the certificate doesn't match with the one that is set in the app.

So my question is how I can go further?

Answer (score 1):

If you're a Windows user, as a matter of dynamic analysis, you could try using an emulator like [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/), then inspect your system network traffic with a program like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Additionally, you could use a program like [Cheat Engine](https://github.com/cheat-engine/cheat-engine) to open the BlueStacks process and scan its memory for strings related to URLs. As an aside, you could statically analyze the APK by unpacking/decompressing it, then comb through its files looking for relevant strings.

Back to Cheat Engine, you could ultimately write a script in Assembly or Lua to automate certain tasks--or you could just change certain values in memory if there is weak server validation (or none at all).

Perhaps a significantly easier solution all around is to use something like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), which would allow you to script mouse movements and keystrokes. At that rate, all you have to do is install the game in the emulator, then script whatever process(es) you need to script for automation.

Comment: Would you recommend using the emulator from the android sdk instead of bluestacks? I'm doing a similar project but the specific app does not run on bluestacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can emulate the application, you could try to look at the hooking method :) for example take a look to:

- [xposed framework](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed) -  a simple [example](https://blog.squareroots.de/en/2015/12/seccon-2015-online-ctf-reverse-engineering-android-apk-1/) - and [another](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial)
- [frida](https://www.frida.re/docs/examples/android/) - It’s a dynamic code instrumentation toolkit

Xposed Framework requires root access to install.
Also Frida require a rooted phone.
Then you can edit for example the parameters of the function which controls the certificate

Comment: Is your suggestions work for an app that is downloaded from the play store?

Comment: Yes, if you are able to emulate it, otherwise you need a rooted phone

Comment: Try to look this http://repo.xposed.info/module/kmod.xposed